# Faster way of calculating hamming distance in numpy array with long bitstrings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hamming-distance, bitstring

I am trying to achieve faster computation time when calculating hamming distance with numpy arrays having close to 2 million bitstrings with each bitstring have a length of 1280.

My current implementation takes about close to 4 seconds which is quite bad for my case. My current approach:

```
>>> A = np.array(['00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001101110000000000000000000000000000000000000000100011000100001000000000000000100011110101111011110000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000001001100011000110000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000100011000010000000000000010001100001000000000000001000011000110000000010000000001000010000100000000000000100001000010000000000000010000110001100000001100001000000000100001000010000100001000010000100000000000000000000000000000000001000010000100001000110000100011000010000100001000000000000000000000000000000000000000100011000010000100001000010000100001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'])

>>> A = A.repeat(2000000,axis=0)
>>> B = A

>>> A.shape
(2000000,)
>>> B.shape
(2000000,)

>>> first=(np.fromstring(A, dtype=np.uint8)-48).reshape(-1,1280)
>>> second=(np.fromstring(B, dtype=np.uint8)-48).reshape(-1,1280)

>>> hamm_dist = (first!=second).sum(1)

>>> hamm_dist.shape
(2000000,)
```

Is there any faster way that could bring my computation time down to less than a second or better?

Comment: *"...bring my computation time down to less than a second or better?"*  Your arrays each have more than 2.5e9 elements.  A comparison must be made for each element.  How fast is your computer?  If it runs at, say, 2.5 gigahertz, you're not going to get much better than a few seconds for the total computation if you use a serial algorithm.  To get a significant improvement, you'll need some form of parallel computation.

Comment: In the actual scenario, I have billions of those arrays and eventually I will be doing some parallelism but I believe the computation time will still be a problem since  I can't get the base case running in real time.